# ElasticSearch select distinct from a large number of documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with ~100 million documents. Sometimes I want to retrieve all documents, sometimes I want to group by a particular field, selecting only one document for each unique value. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM documents GROUP BY my_field;
```

To illustrate, sometimes I want to get:

```
|id|my_field|thing  |
|--|--------|-------|
|1 |a       |red    |
|2 |b       |yellow |
|3 |b       |green  |
|4 |c       |brown  |
```

and sometimes

```
|id|my_field|thing  |
|--|--------|-------|
|1 |a       |red    |
|3 |b       |green  |
|4 |c       |brown  |
```

The ElasticSearch documents suggest that [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation) fits this use. However, there is the suggestion that this is only suitable for small cardinalities of the aggregated term, i.e. a small number of 'buckets':

> Sometimes there are too many unique terms to process in a single request/response pair so it can be useful to break the analysis up into multiple requests

In addition to this, the [Top Hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) returns data in a format that doesn't look like it can be paginated easily.

If I had, for example, a million distinct terms, I looks like it wouldn't be well aligned with the intended design. Is this correct?

My alternative is to maintain an index and flag duplicates in my own code, but this is error-prone, subject to concurrency issues etc.

Is there a way to achieve what I want that plays to the strengths of ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this isn't the best use case for ElasticSearch indexes / aggregation. I solved my problem another way - by creating a separate type (or index) which stored the deduplicated view of my data. I used a hash of the unique pair as the `_id` field, so ElasticSearch automatically deduplicates documents as they come in.

As a bonus feature, using an external `_timestamp` allows me to choose which document gets stored in the case of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Now in Elasticsearch you can use the [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html).

> **The composite aggregation is expensive. Load test your application before deploying a composite aggregation in production.**
>
> A multi-bucket aggregation that creates composite buckets from different sources.
>
> Unlike the other `multi-bucket` aggregations, you can use the `composite`
> aggregation to paginate **all** buckets from a multi-level aggregation
> efficiently. This aggregation provides a way to stream **all** buckets of
> a specific aggregation, similar to what [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results) does for documents.
>
> The composite buckets are built from the combinations of the values
> extracted/created for each document and each combination is considered
> as a composite bucket.

It's a bit late to your question, but it might help others.

Comment: Thanks very much! Take an upvote, but it's been too long to evaluate your answer against my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are correct in your assessment that, while the cardinality agg fits here, the scale at which you may encounter distinct values would create problems. [This type of aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html) is the closest thing to a "GROUP BY" that I'm aware of in ElasticSearch.

That being said, I think there is a way you can accomplish

> selecting only one document for each unique value.

via multiple queries nested within a "Should" parent.

Your approach will vary much differently depending on if you are aiming only for aggregate counts, or returned values.

My initial inclination would be to treat your request as a set of sibling queries nested within should. The problem with that approach would be returning based on most fields matched, rather than the first document of each distinct query. As far as I'm aware of, there isn't any type of scoring for "should" queries that return a single match for each bucket.

With the goal of returning documents, I believe you would be best suited to execute a [multi-search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) :

```
POST _msearch
{"index":"INDEX"}
{"query":{"match": {"a": "red"}},"size":1}
{"index":"INDEX"}
{"query":{"match": {"b": "yellow"}},"size":1}
{"index":"INDEX"}
{"query":{"match": {"b": "green"}},"size":1}
```

The above will return you a single document matching each query, giving you a response with an array of "result" objects.

Raw counts:

```
POST /INDEX/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "a_red": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "a": {
            "value": "red"
          }
        }
      }
    },        
    "b_yellow": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "b": {
            "value": "yellow"
          }
        }
      }
    },        
    "b_green": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "b": {
            "value": "green"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the above example's agg bucket names (ex: "a_red") are just for clarity, they aren't required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be clear, at my scale I think that would require returning all 1 million distinct values of `my_field`, then a 1-million-arity multisearch? I think this fundamentally doesn't play to ElasticSearch's intended use.

Comment: With the data structure you demonstrated, I would agree with you (assuming cardinality will bomb out with this many distinct values). If you are able to tweak how you're ingesting content, I believe you may have better results. 

Have you considered normalizing your data to a set of documents that have only the values you're interested (and ref field(s))? With that approach, you may be able to include a script that will insert a document to another type or index that is populated with a document per cardinal value, a counter that the script increments, and a list of reference docs.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my question I could do maintain my own index, but it could cause concurrency issues and I was trying to investigate using a native ElasticSearch method. I think it's my only option, however.